# How to lock a graph window in R

Tags: r, graph, plot, window

I have a data collecting and graph plotting program written in R running on a shared computer where someone might accidentally close my plotting window.

Is there a way to lock the plotting window so that no one can close the plotting window just by clicking the close button? Or at least it will popup a warning dialog when someone attempt to close the window?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just save your plots to files?

Comment: It's a real time plotting program, I need to see how the data are going in real time :)

Comment: Well, plots are viewed in applications other than R, so I don't believe that there is a way to do this strictly in R.

Comment: Well you could save the plots and have them display normally - then if somebody closes the plot you could just open the file you saved...

Comment: :( That's so sad. But is there a workaround using another program?

Comment: What do you mean by real time plot? you can't save the plot each time you refresh it so you get the last version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the "StickyNote" package, which isn't on CRAN but can be got from your stationery cupboard:

```
require(stickynote)
note = createNote("Computer busy, please don't use!", colour="yellow", pen="black")
attachNote(note, PC)
```

when your code is finished:

```
removeNote(note,PC)
```

What I'm saying here is that a technological solution is not always the best thing. Putting a sticky note on the PC might also stop people turning it off, closing other windows and so on.

There are actual programs for putting virtual yellow sticky notes on computer screens. You could just put one of these over your R graphics window so that any user would have to move it to get to your graphics window, but there's not one for R. A quick google shows there may be one included in Windows 7 under Accessories: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-sticky-notes-in-windows-7.html

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can achieve this with R alone, however you can write a Java program that connects to R and display the plot in Java windows where you will have more control over e.g. display a warning on close etc.

If you want to implement this solution, you can will need these tools [R and Java integration](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/files/)